# Using MS SQL PHP 5.6

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php-5.6

I've been working on MySQL servers alot but for a project i'm working i need to use a MSSQL Server.

Currently the only way to connect to a MSSQL Database is by using the Extensions and installing the Drivers for MSSQL. Now i was wondering if there is a way to use MSSQL Servers without having to install all of this. I'm trying to keep it as simplistic as possible for the 'User' of this project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Certainly there are theoretical alternatives like using a cli client from within php or even creating your own socket client. But what for? You will get endless issues because you are obviously reeventing the wheel and a very complex well actually. So this certainly is _not_ a good idea.

Comment: Found mssql in php but im guessing thats deprecated ?

Comment: Why that? If in doubt, then why dont you simply take a look at the documentation?

Comment: i did and when im using these functions it says that the functions dont exists thats why i'm guessing its deprecated

Comment: If they were deprecated that would be clearly stated in the documentation. That's what a documentation is there for. Above you wrote "found mssql in php", but now I guess not inside you installation? So either the extension is not installed (check for the file) or it is simply not activated (check your php configuration).

Comment: This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later

Found the above text on another StackOverflow answer. I had the extension enabled in the configuration (it was commented) tried it didn't work. And i looked for the file and its not in my extension folder. (Xampp PHP.ini) why the hell still include this line commented in a fresh installation if the file isn't even in the extension folder. Thanks anyway @arkascha

Comment: Hm, interesting. I have only very limited experience with MS-Windows based systems. But I'd say there must be a reason for why the extension is not bundled any more. Note however that that is an xampp problem most likely, not a php issue. But I agree that on an MS-Windows system you have very little alternatives now, since the complete lack of a package management system and a central software repository where you could easily build yourself from source a version of xampp that does contain that extension. It might be worth checking that distributions web page (xampp) for the reason...